# Email notifications for disqus comments on a node

Tags: notifications, comments

I setup a blog in drupal and used the disqus module to integrate it with the disqus commenting system.  The drupal commenting system isn't used.  When someone posts a disqus comment on the node, I'd like drupal to email the node author a notification of the comment.  Disqus' system is setup to notify a primary administrative account when a new comment is posted but not the node author, as that information lies within Drupal. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not supported out of the box. There are a few solutions:

- Use http://drupal.org/node/1117622 to fire a callback to Drupal to notify the author.
- Sync disqus with the Drupal comment system. The module supports it, but I haven't tested.